# Can map-reduce speed up the count-min-sketch algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, online-algorithms, mapreduce

Is there any possibility of improvement in the result of count-min-sketch algorithm if we will use Map Reduce approach?
Improvement in performance can be in terms of accuracy, time complexity or the work done needed.

Comment: The result should be the same; you mean, will it be faster?

Comment: What kind of improvement?  Speed?  Asymptotic running time or efficiency in practice?  Speedup compared to what?  Why do you think there might be a possibility of speedup?  What are your thoughts?  Please edit your question to elaborate.  A one-sentence question is rarely sufficient.  I encourage you to flesh out and develop your question.  Give us something to work with...

Comment: First answer that comes to mind is that you’d want a good sparse representation of a sketch. Second is that, if it’s relatively unlikely that many threads will try to write to the same location simultaneously, you could paralellize with a CAS loop on update.

Answer (score 1):

yes. section 3.2 from [here](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~graham/pubs/papers/cmsoft.pdf).

> A key feature of the operations which manipulate the sketch is that
>   they are largely oblivious to the current state of the data structure.
>   That is, the updates to the sketch do not require inspection of the
>   current state. This means that data structure is highly suitable for
>   parallelization and distributed computation. Firstly, each row of the
>   sketch is updated independently of others, so the sketch can be
>   partitioned row-wise among threads on a single machine. But more than
>   this, one can build sketches of different subsets of the data (after
>   agreeing on the same parameters w, d and set of hash functions to
>   use), and these sketches can be combined to give the sketch of the
>   union of the data. Sketch combination is straightforward: given sketch
>   arrays of size w × d, they are combined by summing them up,
>   entry-wise. This implies that sketches can be a useful tool in large
>   scale data analysis, within a distributed model such as MapReduce.
>   Each machine can build and “emit” a sketch of its local data, and
>   these can then be combined at a single machine (i.e. a single reducer
>   simply sums up all the sketches, entry-wise) to generate the sketch of
>   a potentially huge collection of data. This approach can be
>   dramatically more efficient in terms of network communication (and
>   hence time and other resources) than the solution of computing exact
>   counts for each item, and filtering out the low counts.